# Symfony2 form_widget datetime : an hour without leading zeros

Tags: symfony, twig

**formType**

```
->add("someday", DateTimeType::class, [
    "date_widget" => "single_text",
    "minutes"     => ["00", "20", "40"],
    "required"    => true,
])
```

**template**

```
{{ form_widget(form.someday.date) }}
{{ form_widget(form.someday.hour) }}
{{ form_widget(form.someday.minute) }}
```

**Generated HTML (on hour part)**

```
<select id="form_someday_time_hour" name="form[someday][time][hour]">
    <option value="0">00</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13" selected="selected">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

---

In this case, selectbox of hour with leading zeros（00, 01, 02 ... 23）,
but I would like to change this selectbox without leading zeros(0, 1, 2 ... 23).

**I would like to generate HTML of this format. (on hour part)**

```
<select id="form_someday_time_hour" name="form[someday][time][hour]">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13" selected="selected">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

I tried specifying the format in the form type, but there was no change.

Will there be options for the widget on the template side?

Thank you if you know.

Comment: Check my EDIT #2, try it please.

Comment: I think that it will not be fixed with the date filter. If there is a solution, I think it is an option of form widget or form type option. A description has been added of generated HTML.

Comment: See my EDIT #3. Do I at least deserve some kind of up vote?

Comment: Edit #4 one last try...

Answer (score 0):

Try [the Twig date filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) and specify the hour format without leading zeros like so:

```
{{ form_widget(form.someday.hour|date('h')) }}
```

Formats are specified using [the DateInterval.format](http://www.php.net/DateInterval.format). I think that should work for you. Please try it.

---

EDIT #2

I'm not sure why you are getting that error. Maybe it's because the date filter is in the wrong place? Can you try this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.someday.hour)|date('h') }}
```

I'm not sure if that will fix it, but please try it. If that doesn't work, maybe you can tell me how you want the "date", "hour" and "minute" to be rendered in HTML format (update your question post to show that); then maybe we can use the formatting of the DateTimeType field.

---

EDIT #3

Why not try this then:

```
$hours = new array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
    array_push($hours, strval($i));
}

...
->add("someday", DateTimeType::class, [
    "date_widget" => "single_text",
    "minutes"     => ["00", "20", "40"],
     "hours"        => $hours,
    "required"    => true,
])
```

I think that will work for you.

---

EDIT #4

Try this as well.

```
->add("someday", DateTimeType::class, [
    "format" => "dd H mm",
    "minutes"     => ["00", "20", "40"],
    "required"    => true,
])
```

Then will be shown as drop down lists. Not sure why you were using `date_widget`???

Comment: It does not seem to work. `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string").`

Comment: #3 : I tried it already. I also tried the range function. However, leading zero will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's impossible.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f7d9701cdfaf9be6b40f661d0d9ec973dc4b904b/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/TimeType.php#L74

Looking at the code, recognized added leading zeros here.

If rewrite like this, it may be the expected behavior.

```
- $hours[str_pad($hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)] = $hour;
+ $hours[$hour] = $hour;
```